# FileNotFoundException on IBM Data DB2 connection

Tags: c#, .net, database, db2, odbc

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and .net451 and I try to connect to an IBM Db2 database, but when I debug my code I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundException
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Additional information: Could not possible to load file or assembly 'IBM.Data.DB2, Version=11.5.5.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208' or one of yours dependencies. The system can't find the file.
```

What can I do to solve this?

I have already installed the NuPackage IBM.Data.DB2 and already set `Copy local` to `false` and `true`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the driver. I got the following message without the driver when connecting to the DB2 database  (see picture):

[image: Error 7c307b91aa13d208]

After installing ibm_data_server_driver_package_win64_v11.1.exe, the issue is fixed.